# Is there any method to get an attribute value from another html file using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Can we use jQuery to get an attribute value by load function?

```
$(#id).load('url of page #source id').attr();
```

Comment: Nope - Why do you want the attribute, might be feasible to use a storage method like cookies / local storage

Comment: Maybe you can take a look for ajax, load back content by url

Answer (score 2):

I quite really didn't understood what you are looking for, Hope this helps, :D

You want to add ul inside your div `new-projects`, and you need to get attribute of `ul` element. You can do as follows

Suppose HTML is like this

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>load demo</title>
  <style>
  body {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: Arial;
  }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<b>Projects:</b>
<div id="new-projects"></div>

<script>
$( "#new-projects" ).load("/load.html #projects ul", function(data){
  var x = data;
  $(x).find('ul').attr('style');  //console.log or alert this
} );
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

load.html

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="projects">
      <ul style="color:blue">
        <li>Test</li>
        <li> This</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```